# Is there a jQuery lightbox plugin that has thumbnails inside the box?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a lightbox style plugin in jQuery that displays thumbnails at the bottom of the picture (or video, or whatever).

I found plenty of lightbox plugins, but none that allows navigation by thumbnail *inside* the box. The plugin must be able to open images, swf and inline content. I realize that jQuery will not be able to generate the thumbnails and that's ok.

Do you have any good ones to suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this should be asked on StackOverflow?

Comment: I hesitated to put it on StackOverflow as it's not a programming question, but a "do you know a plugin" question... But I'll post it there and the worst that will happen is that my question will be closed! ;)

Comment: It will be closed as they do not allow cross-posting. I believe this is the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: Just realized these comments were a couple of years old :s

Answer (score 4):

I use the HighSlide (.com) lightbox. My implementation can be viewed [here](http://www.fietsclub-remunj.nl/pagina/fotoalbum). Select an album, then click on a photo. Thumbnails are at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look for this before but couldn't find the exact thing. I did find these though and they might be useful to you:

http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/

http://slideshowpro.net/

Not really jQuery though :(

Answer (score 0):

prettyPhoto is what I use : http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto

see the image gallery demo.

It has thumbnails inside the main image and it uses jquery.